# MySQL: fetch unique rows from one table while sorting by another's column

Tags: mysql, sql, associations

I my Rails application I want to render a block of Blogs that have most recent Posts as their children. However the question itself is not Rails-specific and It will be fine to see plain-SQL answer.
The data structure is:
`posts` table, `blogs` table; `blogs` have `blogs.id` while `posts` reference them by foreign key `posts.blog_id`.
What I am trying to do:

```
SELECT distinct blogs.id, blogs.* FROM `blogs` INNER JOIN `posts` ON `posts`.`blog_id` = `blogs`.`id` ORDER BY posts.created_at desc, posts.id desc LIMIT 5
```

But I get records in wrong order. When I remove `distinct blogs.id` from the query, I get proper ordering, but then I have duplicate Posts in results.
I understand that I am using wrong approach for this task... but what is the proper one?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT blogs.* 
FROM `blogs` 
INNER JOIN 
(
select distinct blog_id
from posts
ORDER BY posts.created_at desc, posts.id desc 
LIMIT 5
) p ON p.`blog_id` = `blogs`.`id`
```

Comment: ...for some reason i get 3 blogs (there are more) instead of 5 and they are unordered.